# Javascript debugging for IE6/7

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464644/debugging-javascript-for-ie6) but that was three years ago and Microsoft Script Debugger is no longer supported.

Are there any more recent tools out there to help me debug Javascript for IE6/7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio for that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18921/Using-Visual-Studio-to-Debug-JavaScript-in-IE
Btw, Microsoft Script Debugger is still available for download : http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22185 and it should still work fine for debugging script in Microsoft browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, for IE7 you should be able to use IE9 on Windows 7 or Vista.  In IE9, open the developer tools (F12) on the page and switch "browser mode" to "IE7 standard" and "document mode" to "IE7 standard".  Now your IE9 displays pages and runs JS just like an IE7 would - and for all purposes and checks it will be seen as IE7 - yet you have all the IE9 debugging tools available to you.  This was a god-send for me debugging issues on my site.

Unfortunately though, this doesn't work for IE6, because that mode is not available.

Comment: When this works, it's great - but you have to be careful because even though you're using the IE7 rendering mode, you're still using the IE9 JS engine. There are subtle differences.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this. I remember a couple of JS-specific issues that cropped up when running in IE7 mode.

Answer (score 0):

[DebugBar](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/Doc/HomePage) is the most actively maintained plugin. There are also a few bookmarklets:

- [JavaScript Shell](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000287.html)
- [Eval and Dump](http://www.phpied.com/two-bookmarklets-for-debugging-in-ie/)
- [Mouseover DOM Inspector](http://slayeroffice.com/?c=/content/tools/modi.html)